# how to write multiple dataframe to a single csv file in a loop in R?

Tags: r, csv

I would like to write a multiple dataframe "neighbours_dataframe" in a single CSV file :

I use this line to write the multiple dataframe to multiple file :

```
for(i in 1:vcount(karate)){
write.csv(neighbours_dataframe[[i]], file = as.character(V(karate3)$name[i]),row.names=FALSE)}
```

if I use this code:

```
for(i in 1:vcount(karate)){
write.csv(neighbours_dataframe[[i]], file = "karate3.csv",row.names=FALSE)}
```

this would give me just the last dataframe in the csv file  :

I was wondering , How could I have a single CSV file which have all the dataframe in the way that the column header of the first dataframe just written to the csv file and all other data frame copied in a consecutive manner ?

thank you in advance

Comment: If all data.frames have the same set of column names, try `do.call(rbind, neighbours_dataframe)` (assuming `neighbours_dataframe` is a list of data.frames), then write the result of that to a csv. If they don't all share the same columns, then try `dplyr::rbind_all(neighbours_dataframe)`.

Comment: Set `append=TRUE` and it should work.

Comment: @Neal `append` won't work for `write.csv` - see [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26968244/489704) below.

Comment: thak you @Neal as jbaums said append didn't work and I get the warnings and also it was just like the second line code nothing happened

Comment: thank you so much @jbaums, it just work well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two methods; the first is likely to be a little faster if `neighbours_dataframe` is a long list (though I haven't tested this).

**Method 1: Convert the list of data frames to a single data frame first**

As suggested by jbaums.

```
library(dplyr)
neighbours_dataframe_all <- rbind_all(neighbours_dataframe)
write.csv(neighbours_dataframe_all, "karate3.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

**Method 2: use a loop, appending**

As suggested by Neal Fultz.

```
for(i in seq_along(neighbours_dataframe))
{
  write.table(
    neighbours_dataframe[[i]], 
    "karate3.csv", 
    append    = i > 1, 
    sep       = ",", 
    row.names = FALSE,
    col.names = i == 1
  )
}
```

Comment: `append` isn't possible for `write.csv`. See `?write.table`, which states, for CSV files, *"These wrappers are deliberately inflexible: they are designed to ensure that the correct conventions are used to write a valid file. Attempts to change append, col.names, sep, dec or qmethod are ignored, with a warning."*. Instead, you might have to do something like: `write.table(neighbours_dataframe[[i]], "karate3.csv", append = i > 1, row.names = FALSE, col.names = i==1, sep=',')` (within your `for` loop).

Comment: @jbaums Good spot; fixed.

Comment: I think you *do* need to suppress row names as well, though, otherwise column names aren't correctly aligned. See `L <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=1:3); L <- list(d, d); f <- tempfile(fileext='.csv'); for(i in seq_along(L)) write.table(L[[i]], f, append=i>1, sep=",", col.names=i==1); file.show(f)`.

Comment: thank you @RichieCotton, the first method just work perfectly fine on rather long list