# Export multiple dataframes to one Excel Sheet with r

Tags: r, excel

I have around 30 different data frames in r and I want them to be in one Excel sheet, with the dataframe name as well.

For output I'm looking for something like this:

```
dfname1
col1    col2
  x        x
  x        x
dfname2
col1    col3
  x        x
```

How should I do this as an iterative process?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to write multiple dataframe to a single csv file in a loop in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967727/how-to-write-multiple-dataframe-to-a-single-csv-file-in-a-loop-in-r)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: easy way to export multiple data.frame to multiple excel worksheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713310/r-easy-way-to-export-multiple-data-frame-to-multiple-excel-worksheets)

Comment: The first suggested method places all of them into a csv but does not have the name above each new df

Comment: Not duplicate. OP needs it all in a single Excel spreadsheet. To be fare, it's been almost 2 years after and I haven't found other but this question asking it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like a bad idea to intersperse data frame names with data in the same worksheet, but that's up to you.

Anyway, use `openxlsx`. Here's a way to do it:

```
dfname1 <- data.frame(col1 = c("x", "x"), col2 = c("x", "x"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dfname2 <- data.frame(col1 = c("x"), col3 = c("x"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df_list <- list(dfname1=dfname1,
                dfname2=dfname2)

library(openxlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Foo")

curr_row <- 1
for(i in seq_along(df_list)) {
  writeData(wb, "Foo", names(df_list)[i], startCol = 1, startRow = curr_row)
  writeData(wb, "Foo", df_list[[i]], startCol = 1, startRow = curr_row+1)
  curr_row <- curr_row + nrow(df_list[[i]]) + 2
}

saveWorkbook(wb, "bar.xlsx")
```

This gives you (literally) what you asked for.

Comment: That works a charm. But why would it be a bad idea "intersperse data frame names with data in the same worksheet"? I've been doing it to kinda concatenate lots of statistics tests and never saw a problem.