# how transform multiple data.frame in a resume table

Tags: r

I have two data frames like this:

```
DATAFRAME1= data.frame(TYPE =c("X","Y"), 
                       ` COLUMN A`=c(1000, 4000),
                       ` COLUMN B`=c(9000,2000))

DATAFRAME2 = data.frame(TYPE =c("X","Y"), 
             ` COLUMN A`=c(8000,2000),
             ` COLUMN B`=c(5000,10000))
```

I would like create a excel in same sheet like this

[RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rno4z.png)

I don't know how create the resume table, but I already created the first time using this code:

```
library(openxlsx)
df_list <- list("DATAFRAME 1" = DATAFRAME1,
                "DATAFRAME 2" = DATAFRAME2)

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Foo")

curr_row <- 1
for(i in seq_along(df_list)) {
  writeData(wb, "Foo", names(df_list)[i], startCol = 1, startRow = curr_row)
  writeData(wb, "Foo", df_list[[i]], startCol = 1, startRow = curr_row+1)
  curr_row <- curr_row + nrow(df_list[[i]]) + 2
}

saveWorkbook(wb, "WB.xlsx",overwrite=TRUE)
```

Comment: You may need to give a more complete toy data example (including `NA`'s for instance) which fully mimics your real data.

Answer (score 0):

One way which works for the toy data given.

Assuming your data frames are of the same dimension. First, create `RESUME` by hand:

```r
get_nums = \(x) x |> t() |> c() |> unname() |> { \(.) .[!grepl("^X$|^Y$", x = .)] }()

n = ncol(DATAFRAME1) - 1L
RESUME = data.frame(TYPE = c(rep("X", n), rep("Y", n)), 
                    DATAFRAME1 = get_nums(DATAFRAME1), 
                    DATAFRAME2 = get_nums(DATAFRAME2))
```

*Note. There are certainly more elegant and less error-prone approaches out there. Without knowing your "real data structure" it is difficult to give concrecte advice.*

Then, put `RESUME` in your list `df_list`:

```r
df_list = list("DATAFRAME 1" = DATAFRAME1,
               "DATAFRAME 2" = DATAFRAME2, 
               "RESUME" = RESUME)
```

Finally, run the routine (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434732/export-multiple-dataframes-to-one-excel-sheet-with-r)):

```r
curr_row = 1L
for(i in seq_along(df_list)) {
  writeData(wb, "Foo", names(df_list)[i], startCol = 1L, startRow = curr_row)
  writeData(wb, "Foo", df_list[[i]], startCol = 1L, startRow = curr_row + 1L)
  curr_row <- curr_row + nrow(df_list[[i]]) + 2L
}
saveWorkbook(wb, "WB.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you! if there is a character column, are there other way?

Comment: Updated `get_nums()`. As I mentioned, please provide accurate toy data which mimics your real data.